# Website down after moving to another hosting Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I have moved both my website and domain to another host. I get the "forbidden" error when trying to access it. I have not yet changed the MySQL details in parameters in Symfony but I do not think that is the case.

What else shall I modify/change to have the Symfony app working on the new server?

Comment: why would you move the domain before the new server is working properly? check file permissions though

Comment: It has been fixed, happened to be domain downtime while transfering. Although another error occured with my Database.   I have updated the parameters file with the new details of the database although it still does not work. Am I supposed to update it also somewhere else?

Comment: depends on your setup. but maybe you could provide some error log messages? (remove credentials)

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'OLDDBUSERNAME'@'%' to database 'OLDDBNAME'

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/deployment.html i think you have to modify your app/config/parameters.yml for the new database credentials.

Comment: Sadly I did, and it still gives this error especially with the OLDDBNAME string which is strange

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: did you also run the `composer install` command?

Comment: Hey, I havent installed the composer. How shall I do this? Shall I paste the file or where is it located? In root? Anything to be done after composer install?